# JSF, how to express a required attribute

Tags: jsf-2

I want to check the calendar input while the Save button is clicked. It means if I clicked other buttons or do anything else, it would not check input. How to express it ?

Comment: I want to use the required attribute. I just don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a button onClick event handler function in javascript
2. In the onClick event handler function, you can access the HTML document (DOM) ant its elements (For convenience you can use jquery). You can get the attribute value using this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `required` tag in your calendar and use the `process` tag in your Save `commandButton` like this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText id="otherinput" value="Other inputs..."/>
    <p:calendar id="calendar" required="true"/>

    <p:commandButton process="calendar" value="Save"/>
    <p:commandButton process="otherinput" value="Other Button"/>

</h:form>
```

This way when you click the "Save" button it will only `process` the `calendar` and not the other elements. Also when you click the "Other Button" it will not check the calendar.

I assumed here that you are using [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/index.xhtml) as your 3rd party JSF component provider since you didn't mention any, let alone post any sample code you've tried.

Hope this helps